# Keep menu item highlighted

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a menu: http://jsfiddle.net/hu5x3hL1/1/

**HTML**

```
<ul id="menu" class="sidebar">
<li> <a href="#" class="clickme">Menu</a>
    <ul id="menu1">
        <li><a class="dropdown-class-name" href="#">Dropdown link1</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-class-name" href="#">Dropdown link2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

**jQuery**

```
    $('#menu1 li a').click(function(e) {
    $('a').removeClass('dropdown-class-name active');
    $(this).addClass('dropdown-class-name active');
});
```

**CSS**

```
#menu1 li a.active{
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Active menu item is highlighted in bold. But on my web-site when I click some drop down link, the new page opens, but active menu item already isn't bold. How to keep it highlighted in bold on the new page of the web-site?

I tried do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var url = window.location.href;
        $("#menu1 li a").click(function () {
            if (url == (this.href)) {
                $('a').removeClass('dropdown-class-name active');
                $(this).addClass('dropdown-class-name active');
            }
        });
    });
```

I think it's the right idea, but where can be mistake?

Comment: You have to remove `$("#menu1 li a").click()` event. This block of code has to run on document load, not on click of the button.

Comment: I also tried to use `each` instead of `click`, but the result is the same

Comment: Please try to make an `alert()` of **url** and **this.href** to be sure that match.

Comment: @emmanuel alert of `this.href` returns `undefined`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is that when you click a link it causes a reload of the menu and loses the state of the active link. You're setting the menu item active on the old page, then browser follows page to the new page, where it's not active anymore, as the HTML is loaded again and it doesn't have any active classes set on the menu items.

What you have to do instead is to have a Javascript function on page load that checks which menu item corresponds to the current URL and sets that item active. Thus it'll set the active class after the link is followed & new page is loaded and you'll actually see it on the new page.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var url = window.location

  var menuItem = $('#menu1 li a').filter(function() {
    return this.href == url;
  })

  menuItem.addClass('active');
})
```

Comment: I understood the idea, but the result of your code is the same

Comment: It's a little hard to help much more without having more hints. In your question all of the links share same URL, so it's an all or nothing kind of situation, when comparing the links by URL.

Comment: When I use this code I have 2 problems: 1) alert of `this.href` returns `undefined` 2) If I use some link instead of `this.href`, on the new page of the web site all menu items are bold

Comment: Well, the question really is: if all your links point to the same URL, how can you decipher them by URL and how do you actually handle linking to different pages from the menu items?